# Why Doesn't Modal FadeOut Slowly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modalviewcontroller

I inherited this modal/overlay/content close/empty method that works, but abruptly:

```
method.close = function () {
    $modal.hide();
    $overlay.hide();
    $content.empty();
    $(window).unbind('resize.modal');
};
```

To fade out gradually, I modified the method like below, but elements are left behind and subsequent clicks don't open new modals loaded with content, only the overlay:

```
method.close = function () {
    $modal.fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $overlay.fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $content.fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $(this).empty();
    });
    $(window).unbind('resize.modal');
};
```

What am I missing?

UPDATE: The solution is a single nested callback, based on garryp's answer, like this:

```
method.close = function() {
    $overlay.fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $overlay.hide();
        $content.empty();
    });
    $modal.hide();
    $(window).unbind('resize.modal');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide is asynchronous; the calls you have in your original code do not block while the transition occurs, execution moves immediately to the next. You need to use callbacks, like this:

```
var me = $(this); //Added to ensure correct this context
$modal.fadeOut('slow', function () {
    me.hide(function () {
        $overlay.fadeOut('slow', function () {
            me.hide(function () {
                $content.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    me.empty();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Assuming the rest of your code is correct this should ensure the transitions fire one after the next.

Comment: Your nested callback idea put me on the right track, so I added an update with the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you do not need `$(this).hide()`. JQuery `fadeOut` automatically set `display: none` at the end of fading animation (read more: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

That mean, in your case `$content` element will also have `display: none` after `fadeOut` animation. I expect you forgot to add `$content.show()` in modal `open` method.